# Is there any way i can access my APIKEY which is in the .env file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, dotenv

I am consuming an Api and i dont want my API KEY to be exposed to users so i was wondering if there is any way that i can access the key from the .env file using javascript

At this point i had created a variable to store the api_key but it didn't work

```
const api_key = '{{env(API_KEY)}}'
  $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q='+search_for+'&from=2019-09-03&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey='+api_key+'',
      cache:true,
      statusCode:{
        403:function(){
          console.log('403 error');
        },
)};
```

I will appreciate any helping hand
Thank you in advance

Comment: Anything on the client side is exposed to the user.  Especially in this case.  All it takes is for the user to look at their network console to look at the request parameters.  Regardless of how you get the value to build that url, that url is accessable to them via the network console

Comment: If you don't want it exposed to the user, have the user make an ajax request to your server, and then have that server endpoint act as a proxy to the eternal server endpoint and return the response.  At that point, the only thing the client knows is its hitting your server for the info.  Not where your server gets the info

Comment: `const api_key = process.env.API_KEY;` doesn't work? if you need to hide it, you'll have to run the request from browser to node, then have node make the remote fetch and return the payload to the user.

Comment: @Taplar so for my case since i am using django i make a request to a certain view function which will run the api  from the server then return the response to my javascript or?.. Is that what you mean

Comment: I'm not familiar with django to speak with any authority on the subject.  The concept would be the same though.  The server should make the ajax request containing the api key, and return that result to the client.  The client should not make the ajax request directly to the external endpoint, otherwise it would have to know what the api key is.

Comment: @Taplar Thank you soo much.. i think that would work for me.. Thank you once more

Comment: @dandavis i rather go with the method of Taplar since i am not familiar with node..